# Installing SSL Certificate on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: server, ssl

I have uploaded my certificates in the folder /etc/ssl/Cert2023

The files are:

ca.pem
certificate.key
certificate.pem

I created them with open SSL

Now I just want to edit the config file, but I can't find it.

Thought it would be at: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Already looked through https://ubuntu.com/server/docs and this forum, but can't find the solution.

Only did this once so far.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Will these SSL certificates be used for a publicly accessible website? Or will this be limited to something on an intranet/LAN?

Comment: Just Intranet - We will use a reverse proxy if external is needed

Comment: It is unclear what these certificates should be for. Should they be used for a web server, mail server, ...  - and then which of these (nginx, apache, postfix, dovecot, exim ...). Each of the different purposes needs different kind of configuration, so please make sure to a) install the relevant server in the first place and b) follow the documentation of the server on how certificates should be configured there.